# List<String[]> looping issue

Tags: java, for-loop, duplicates

I'm having a duplication problem while trying to add an extra column to a 2D matrix of strings.

Here is my code:

```
List<String[]> rowValues;                      // the matrix, #of rows not  
                                               // important,  #of columns is 7]

String[] columnValues = new String[8];         // would contain the old row 
                                               // data plus one extra String

// LOOP ON ROWS
for(int i = 0; i < rowValues.size(); i++) {

    // LOOP ON COLUMNS
    for (int j = 0; j < rowValues.get(i).length; j++) {
        columnValues[j] = rowValues.get(i)[j];
    }

    columnValues[7] = "ENTRY" + i;
    rowValues.set(i, columnValues);

    System.out.println(rowValues.get(i)[0]);  // last element in each iteration
}
// END LOOPS

System.out.println(rowValues.get(0)[0]);      // element in 0-0 is 
                                              // the same as last row-0
```

My problem is all rows would contain the last row's data, plus the extra column labeled as:
"ENTRYX"

For example,

```
[hi,    im,      haithem]
[this,  is,      hard]
[to,    figure,  out]
```

would be,

```
[to,   figure,  out,  ENTRY2]
[to,   figure,  out,  ENTRY2]
[to,   figure,  out,  ENTRY2]
```

Comment: Do not represent a 2D array as `List<Foo[]>`. Use `List<List<Foo>>`.

Comment: Or simply as `Foo[][]`

Comment: list of array is not a good way to go.

Comment: Can you add the desired result?

Comment: You always operate on single array of `columnValues`, your behavior is as expected given the code. You should use different arrays.

Comment: @ChristofferPass I deliberately elided that. Arrays are inflexible.

Comment: @Michael agreed, but from the code it doesn't seem like it needs to be flexible in size :-)

Comment: @ChristofferPass I didn't mean flexible in size. I meant if you use `List` you can easily swap out the implementation: LinkedList, ArrayList, CopyOnWriteArrayList etc. Arrays should be avoided unless there is a very good reason to use them.

Comment: Thank you guys for your feedback. Unfortunately, I have to use `List<String[]>` because I will pass the result back to a `CSVWriter` method with that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite the values of the `columnValues` variable.

You should declare it inside the loop.

```
List<String[]> rowValues;                      // the matrix, #of rows not  
                                               // important,  #of columns is 7

//////////////////
// LOOP ON ROWS //
//////////////////

for(int i = 0; i < rowValues.size(); i++) {

    final String[] columnValues = new String[8];         // would contain the old row 
                                                         // data plus one extra String

    /////////////////////
    // LOOP ON COLUMNS //
    /////////////////////

    for (int j = 0; j < rowValues.get(i).length; j++) {
        columnValues[j] = rowValues.get(i)[j];
    }

    columnValues[7] = "ENTRY" + i;
    rowValues.set(i, columnValues);


    System.out.println(rowValues.get(i)[0]);  // last element in each iteration
}

///////////////
// END LOOPS //
///////////////

System.out.println(rowValues.get(0)[0]);      // element in 0-0 is
```

Answer (score 0):

You never change `columnValues` to point to a new `String[]`, so in effect `rowValues` contains several references to the *same object*.

Try moving the definition of `columnValues` inside the outer `for` loop, so you create a new `String[]` for every iteration.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What holds the data here are the instances of `String[]`.

You create only one such instance here:

```
String[] columnValues = new String[8];
```

Therefore, you are writing all values in the same place, and you see 3 times the same array because you just added 3 times the same array to the list.

At each turn in the inner loop, you overwrite the content of this single `columnValues` array with new data, and this affects what you already put in the list, because the list simply points multiple times to that single array that you modify over and over again.

To fix your problem, put your line that creates the array inside the outer loop, in order to allocate a new array for each line.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's fixed. I spent an hour staring down at that code.